# Тэг image не отображается в svg в Firefox и IE

Tags: svg, изображения, internet-explorer, firefox

Может у кого-нибудь была такая проблема и есть решение этого.
Я рисую svg с прямоугольником, текстом и картинкой внутри. В `Chrome` работает отлично, но в `Firefox` и `IE` картинка не отображается(если жму F12 и навожу на место где тэг `<image>` должен быть - показывает что нет такого элемента), как это можно исправить?

код(внутри html):

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xlink" width="800" height="250"
                         class="border border-secondary rounded">
    <rect></rect>
    <text x="15" y="45" fill="#ED6E46" font-size="40" font-family="'Leckerli One', cursive">Some text</text>
    <image x="630" y="80" xlink:href='/qrCode' type="image/png" alt="Image"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: добавьте значения `width` и `height` в соответствующие атрибуты `<image />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Совершенно верно сказано в комментариях `@Геннадий Журов`

> добавьте значения width и height в соответствующие атрибуты

Значения можно указывать в процентах или пикселях

*Исправления кода в вопросе*

- В svg нет `Z-index` поэтому нужно следить, чтобы порядок размещения
  объектов не допускал перекрывания. Поэтому сначала `<image>`, затем
  `<rect>`, потом `<text>`
- В шапке svg файла нужно исправить `namespaces`

  `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`
- Если вы выбрали svg, то за мучения должна быть награда -
  адаптивность.  Для этого добавляете `viewBox="0 0 1247 845"` по
  размерам используемой картинки и убираете `width` и `height` из шапки
  svg файла
- Оборачиваете svg код в контейнер `<div class="container">` и с
  помощью процентов регулируете начальный размер svg/
- **Старайтесь не допускать не завершенных, заготовок кода**, как у вас `<rect></rect>` svg парсер проглотит это, не выдаст ошибки, но
  выполнение программы будет остановлено и теги, которые ниже не будут
  выполнены

```css
.container {

width:75%;
height:75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1247 845">
    
    <image  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPFHK.png"
    width="100%" height="100%"> </image>
    <rect x="20" y="60" width="520" height="100"  rx="15" ry="15"  
style="stroke:#ED6E46; stroke-width:4; fill: none;"/>
    
    <text x="35" y="145" fill="#ED6E46" font-size="100px" font-family="'Leckerli One', cursive">Some text</text>
    
</svg>
</div>
```

### Анимация рамки и текста

В качестве развивающего бонуса сделаем анимацию рамки и текста.

Чтобы они двигались вместе объединим их в группу `<g>.. </g>`

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#rect1 {
stroke:#ED6E46;
stroke-width:4;
fill:none;
}

#txt1 {
fill:#ED6E46;
font-size:100px;
font-family:'Leckerli One', cursive;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1247 845">
    
    <image id="img1" width="100%" height="100%"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPFHK.png"> </image>
      <g id="gr1">
  <rect id="rect1" x="20" y="60" width="520" height="100"  rx="15" ry="15"> </rect>  
     <text id="txt1" x="35" y="145">Some text</text> 
  <animateTransform
  attributeName="transform"
  type="translate"
  values="20 65;20 65;700 20;700 20;700 500;700 500;20 65" dur="6s"
  repeatCount="indefinite"

  />
    </g>
</svg>  
</div>
```

Объекты перемещаются по траектории между узловыми точками с координатами - `"x1 y1;x2 y2; x3 y3"`, которые указаны в параметре:

```
values="20 65;20 65;700 20;700 20;700 500;700 500;20 65"
```

Паузы в перемещениях между узловыми точками достигаются повторением координат, той точки, где необходима пауза. `20;700 20;700` и `700 500;700 500`